# Combine scipy.root and Jax Jacobian

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, jax

I am having trouble using the Jacobian from JAX with `scipy.root`. In the below example, the `root` works without the Jacobian, while it fails with the Jacobian. Any ideas on what I need to rewrite in order to get the code below working with the Jacobian?

```
from jax import jacfwd
from scipy.optimize import root
import numpy as np

def objectFunction(valuesEndo, varNamesEndo, valuesExo, varNamesExo, equations): 
  for i in range(len(varNamesExo)):
      exec("%s = %.10f" %(varNamesExo[i], valuesExo[i]))

  for i in range(len(varNamesEndo)):
    exec("%s = %.10f" %(varNamesEndo[i], valuesEndo[i]))
    
  equationVector = np.zeros(len(equations))
  for i in range(len(equations)):
      exec('equationVector[%d] = eval(equations[%d])' %(i, i))    
      
  return equationVector

varNamesEndo = ['x', 'y']
valuesEndoInitialGuess = [1., 1.]

varNamesExo = ['a', 'b']
valuesExo = [1., 1.]

equations = ['a*x+b*y**2-4',
            'np.exp(x) + x*y - 3']

equations = ['a*x**2 + b*y**2',
            'a*x**2 - b*y**2']

# Without Jacobian
sol1 =  root(fun=objectFunction,
            x0=valuesEndoInitialGuess, 
            args=(varNamesEndo, valuesExo, varNamesExo, equations))
#----> Works

# With Jacobian
jac  = jacfwd(objectFunction)
sol2 =  root(fun=objectFunction,
            x0=valuesEndoInitialGuess, 
            args=(varNamesEndo, valuesExo, varNamesExo, equations),
            jac=jac)
#----> Not woring
```

At least there seems to be problems with the line

```
for i in range(len(varNamesEndo)):
        exec("%s = %.10f" %(varNamesEndo[i], valuesEndo[i]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. to perform automatic differentiation, JAX relies on replacing values with tracers. This means your approach of printing and evaluating the string representation of the value will not work.
2. additionally, you are attempting to assign traced values to a standard numpy array. You should use a JAX array instead, as it knows how to handle traced values.

With this in mind, you can rewrite your function this way and it should work, so long as your equations only use Python arithmetic operations and jax functions (not things like `np.exp`):

```python
import jax.numpy as jnp

def objectFunction(valuesEndo, varNamesEndo, valuesExo, varNamesExo, equations): 
  for i in range(len(varNamesExo)):
      exec("%s = valuesExo[%d]" %(varNamesExo[i], i))

  for i in range(len(varNamesEndo)):
    exec("%s = valuesEndo[%d]" %(varNamesEndo[i], i))
    
  equationVector = jnp.zeros(len(equations))
  for i in range(len(equations)):
      equationVector = equationVector.at[i].set(eval(equations[i]))
      
  return equationVector
```

Side-note: this kind of approach based on setting variable names using `exec` is really brittle and error-prone; I'd suggest an approach based on building explicit namespaces for evaluating your equations. For example something like this:

```python
def objectFunction(valuesEndo, varNamesEndo, valuesExo, varNamesExo, equations):
  namespace = {
      **dict(zip(varNamesEndo, valuesEndo)),
      **dict(zip(varNamesExo, valuesExo))
  }
  return jnp.array([eval(eqn, namespace) for eqn in equations])
```